# AlexNet Research Paper VS PytTorch and Tensorflow implementation

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, pytorch, alex-net

I'm making my way through Deep Learning research papers, starting with [AlexNet](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks), and I found differences in the implementation of PyTorch and Tensorflow that I can't explain.

In the research paper, they define the model architecture with:

> The first convolutional layer filters the **224x224x3** input image with
> **96 kernels of size 11x11x3** with a **stride of 4 pixels** (this is the distance between the >  receptive field centers of neighboring neurons in a kernel map).

> The second convolutional layer takes as input the (response-normalized and pooled) output
> of the first convolutional layer and filters it with **256 kernels of size 5x5x**.

> The third, fourth, and fifth convolutional layers are connected to one another **without any
> intervening pooling or normalization layers**.

> The third convolutional layer has **384 kernels of size 3x3x256** connected to the
> (normalized, pooled) outputs of the second convolutional layer.

> The fourth convolutional layer has **384 kernels of size 3x3x192**

> The fifth convolutional layer has **256 kernels of size 3x3x192**.

*Note: Fully Connected layers are not inlcuded*

Here is the [PyTorch implementation](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/models/alexnet.py) of the model:

```
# 1st Layer
nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=11, stride=4, padding=2),
nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),

# 2nd Layer
nn.Conv2d(64, 192, kernel_size=5, padding=2),
nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),

# 3rd Layer
nn.Conv2d(192, 384, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
nn.ReLU(inplace=True),

# 4th Layer
nn.Conv2d(384, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
nn.ReLU(inplace=True),

# 5th Layer
nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2)
```

And the [Tensorflow implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/alexnet.py):

```
# 1st layer
net = slim.conv2d(inputs, 64, [11, 11], 4, padding='VALID', scope='conv1')
net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [3, 3], 2, scope='pool1')

# 2nd layer
net = slim.conv2d(net, 192, [5, 5], scope='conv2')
net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [3, 3], 2, scope='pool2')

# 3rd layer
net = slim.conv2d(net, 384, [3, 3], scope='conv3')

# 4th layer
net = slim.conv2d(net, 384, [3, 3], scope='conv4')

# 5th layer
net = slim.conv2d(net, 256, [3, 3], scope='conv5')
net = slim.max_pool2d(net, [3, 3], 2, scope='pool5')
```

*Note: Tensorflow applies ReLU activation to every layer*

Why both implementations have a first layer with a kernel of 64 where the paper mentions a kernel of 92?

Why both implementations have a second layer with a kernel of 192 where the paper mentions a kernel of 256?

[PyTorch] Why is there a padding of 2 on layers 1 and 2?

[PyTorch] Why is there a kernel of 256 for the 4th layer where it should be a kernel of size 384

Comment: Last question is a bug on PyTorch implementation that they won't fix: https://github.com/pytorch/vision/pull/463#issuecomment-379214941

Comment: First question, kernel 92-64, is a difference with the original implementation due to multi-gpu training: https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/549#issuecomment-512733895